# ruby unable to load rubygems after compilation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have compiled Ruby 193 and was able to load many of the modules without any issues. But when I tried to load 'rubygems' its saying false.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):005:0>
```

But on ruby 1.8.7, to load the json we needed to load rubygems first and only then json will load. Am having little confusion with the rubygems between ruby 193 and 187.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have only said what happens, but you haven't said what you *expect* to happen instead, *why* you expect that to happen, and in what way the expected behavior and the actual behavior differ. What *specifically* is the problem with your code? Why does it matter to you whether `require` returns `false` or `true`?

Comment: My question when I load rubygems why its showing false though gem is working fine.

Comment: Is there anything in the documentation of `Kernel#require` that is particularly unclear? It would be very nice of you if you could tell *what part* precisely of the documentation is unclear to you, so that the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` returns `true` when it loads a module, `false` if the module is already loaded, and raises a `LoadError` when a module cannot be found.

You are not unable to load `rubygems`; it is loaded by default. Try to `require 'smegybur'` or some other nonsense to see how it looks like when a package in fact cannot be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now I understand very well about this.